# Random Sinusoidal Signal, correlation coefficient?

Tags: statistics

Consider a random sinusoidal signal of the form

X(t) = A cos(ωt + Θ),

where ω is assumed fixed and known, and A and Θ are independent random variables,
with Θ being a continuous random variable that is uniformly distributed
over [0, 2π].

(a) Find the correlation coefficient ρ between X(t0) and X(t1), where t0 and t1
are specified sampling times.

(b) Find the linear minimum mean square error (LMMSE) estimator of X(t1)
given the observation X(t0).

(Hint: The distribution of A should not play a role in any of your answers to
the above questions.)

Hi! I'm kind of very lost. I was looking through my textbook, but I have no idea how to do the second part? Any help would be much appreciated. I've already calculated the coefficient to be cos(w($t_1-t_0$)) and the covariance to be $A^2/2$cos(w($t_1-t_0$))

Comment: Question (a): You know that you must first compute the covariance. Have you applied $Cov(X(t_0),X(t_1))=(E(X(t_0)X(t_1))=\int...$

Comment: In fact, question (a) is about autocorrelation.
 See (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518206/finding-the-autocorrelation-of-a-sine-wave)

Comment: I calculated the covariance to be $A^2$ cos(w( $t_1-t_0$ ) and thus the coefficient to be just cos(w( $t_1-t_0$ ) but I'm not quite sure how to solve b

Comment: Why don't you say at once what you have done ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would have been enough to say I needed help on the second part, I'll edit it now!

Comment: Make the following request on Google : LMMSE sinusoidal signal MIT6_011S10_chap08.pdf  You will get a document from MIT OpenCourse. See page 155.