# Velocity Auto-correlation on Spinning Disk

Tags: integration, signal-processing, classical-mechanics, correlation

For a 2D disk of diameter $l$ spinning with angular velocity $\omega$, what is the velocity auto-correlation in the y-direction averaged over the disk?

So far, I have that the y-component of velocity at a point ($r, \theta_0$) is:

\begin{equation}
v_y (r,\theta_0) = \omega r \sin(\theta_0)
\end{equation}

and some time $\tau$ later the point on the disk has rotated by $\Delta \theta = \omega \tau $:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
v_y&= \omega r \sin(\theta_0 + \Delta \theta) \newline
&= \omega r \sin(\theta_0 + \omega \tau) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I think I'm  after the integral $A$ to compute the average (over the disk area of $\pi l^2/4$) auto-correlation:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &= \frac{4}{\pi l^2} \int_0^{l/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v_y(\theta_0) \cdot v_y(\theta_0 + \omega \tau) d\theta_0 dr \newline
&= \frac{4}{\pi l^2} \int_0^{l/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \omega r \sin(\theta_0) \cdot \omega r \sin(\theta_0 + \omega \tau) d\theta_0 dr
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518324) shows the autocorrelation of a sine wave is $\frac{1}{2} \cos(\Delta \theta)$. This works for any point on the disk. So now we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &=\frac{2 \omega^2}{\pi l^2}\cos(\omega \tau)  \int_0^{l/2} r^2dr \newline
&=\frac{l \omega^2}{ 12 \pi }\cos ( \omega \tau)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Are these the right integrals to take, resulting in the auto-correlation being this cosine wave with $\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0} A =  \frac{l \omega^2}{ 12 \pi}$? I'm trying to work out if this working is right and if $A$ represents the auto-correlation of the collective points on the disk.

Comment: Did not check all, but the formula for $\Delta \theta$ should not involve $r$. It should be just $\omega\tau$

Comment: @Andrei thanks I edited this into my solution.